# Why won't Foundation 5 initialize any JavaScript components?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a site built with Foundation, and I'm attempting to upgrade to 5.2.0 to see if Orbit issues are resolved (among other things). I initialize components via data attributes like `data-orbit` and everything works fine when I use an older CDN version in the page footer and initialize like so:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.0.2/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

 <script>
      $(document).foundation();
 </script>
```

I'm only using Orbit, Reveal, Topbar, and Dropdown, so I'd like to build and minify my own 5.2.0 (or master) package. Should be straightforward:

```
 <script src="/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.abide.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.accordion.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.alert.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.clearing.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.equalizer.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.interchange.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.joyride.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.slider.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.tab.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>

 <script>
      $(document).foundation();
 </script>
```

I included everything as a Hail Mary, wondering whether there are cross-dependencies or something, yet every single (previously-working) module fails to load. Things I've checked:

- the include URLs are all working (200 OK), and not cached previous versions or anything
- there are no JavaScript errors on the page, or troublesome console traces of any kind
- using a [minified CDN version of 5.2.0](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/5.2.0/js/foundation.min.js) results in the exact same problem, which leads me to believe it's a 5.2.0 thing—or at least a difference between the only version that works (5.0.2) and any other version I try
- explicitly initializing a component (`$(document).foundation('orbit');`) makes no difference
- I added foundation.min.css from the 5.2.0 package, but it didn't make any difference either
- 5.0.3 appears to work (from cdnjs.cloudflare.com), so now I'm thinking I'm on to something looking at the package change log

Though *every* module breaks, here's an example of my Orbit markup (with EE tags) just in case I've done something dumb:

```
<ul data-orbit class="orbit-container" data-options="bullets:false;timer:false;slide_number:false;">
    {product_images}
        <li class="slide" data-orbit-slide="slide-{file_id}">
            {exp:ce_img:single src='{url}' alt='{alt_text}' width='635' height='476' crop='yes'}
            {if caption}
            <div class="orbit-caption">
                {caption}
            </div>
            {/if}
        </li>
    {/product_images}
    {if product_video}
        <li class="slide" data-orbit-slide="slide-video">
            <div class="flex-video">
                {product_video width="100%"}
            </div>
        </li>
    {/if}
</ul>
```

Is there some other trick to initialization? My understanding is that you need to load fastclick in the page header, load jQuery, then `foundation.js`, then the modules in the footer, and finally call `$(document).foundation()` to initialize any modules utilized on the page. Yet clearly I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the SCSS. You can't compile old SCSS and expect it to work with 5.0.2-5.0.3 AND newer versions of the framework. Package deal, Matt.